# express a cosine product as a single cosine

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

### Problem

I have this expression $c\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2),$

where $c$ is a constant term that eats away any constant factor e.g the following can be considered true:

$$c\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2) = c\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2) / \pi$$

Because both expressions differ only by a constant factor.

$\theta_1\theta_2$ Are free variables. The goal is trying to find an expression of the form
$c\cos(f(\theta_1, \theta_2))$ where $f$ is just a function of the two variables.

### More context

What I am trying to do is, I have two random points $p_1, p_2$ in the unit sphere. And the function:

$f(v) = (v\cdot p_1)(c\cdot p_2) = |v||p_1|\cos(\theta_1)|v||p_2|\cos(\theta_2) = c\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)$ (in this case $c=1$)

The final goal is to find a new point $p_3$ in the sphere such that $v\cdot p_3 = f(v)$

I know there's a whole infinity of such vectors, the nice thing however is that if you find an explicit representation you can just pick one based on nice heuristics, e.g pick one on the line connecting $p_1, p_2$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The "More context" section is asking something different.

Comment: @Makogan Please go through derivation of Cosine Rule in spherical trigonometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you might be looking for the identity
$$2\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2) = \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$$

Unfortunately, it does mean that
$$f(\theta_1, \theta_2) = \arccos\bigr(\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)\bigr) = \arccos\bigr(\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\bigr)$$

Fortunately, it does not matter much in your case.

To recap, you have two unit vectors, $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{v}$, and (many random pairs of) unit vectors $\hat{p}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$, and you want to find a third unit vector $\hat{p}_3$ (per such pair), such that
$$\hat{p}_3 \cdot \hat{v} = (\hat{p}_1 \cdot \hat{v})(\hat{p}_2 \cdot \hat{c}) \tag{1}\label{None1}$$

Since $-1 \le \hat{p}_2 \cdot \hat{c} \le 1$, we can express $\hat{p}_3$ as rotated away from $\hat{p}_1$ around the axis $\vec{a} = \hat{v}\times\hat{p}_1$ enough to make the equation true. (In the case of $\hat{p}_2 \perp \hat{c}$, that angle is zero; $\hat{p}_3 = \hat{p}_1$.)

First, find the unit rotation axis $\hat{a}$:
$$\hat{a} = \frac{\hat{v}\times\hat{p}_1}{\left\lVert\hat{v}\times\hat{p}_1\right\rVert}$$

We rotate $\vec{p}_1$ by angle $\theta$ around unit axis vector $\hat{a}$, using Rodrigues' rotation formula, to obtain the desired vector:
$$\vec{p}_3 = \vec{p}_1\cos\theta + (\hat{a}\times\vec{p}_1)\sin\theta + \hat{a}(\hat{a}\cdot\vec{p}_1)(1 - \cos\theta) \tag{2}\label{None2}$$

Substituting $\eqref{None2}$ into $\eqref{None1}$ and writing it in Cartesian coordinate form yields a function of form
$$C_2 \cos\theta + C_1 \sin\theta + C_0 = 0 \tag{3}\label{None3}$$
where $C_2$, $C_1$, and $C_0$ are constants depending only on $\hat{a}$, $\hat{v}$, $\hat{c}$, $\hat{p}_1$, and $\hat{p}_2$.

When you know $\theta$, substituting it into $\eqref{None2}$ yields the desired $\hat{p}_3$.

Answer (score 1):

A solution (if not *the* solution) is

$$f(\theta_1,\theta_2)=\arccos(c\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)))$$ where $|c|\le1$.

More generally, you can vary the sign of $f$ arbitrarily and add multiples of $2\pi$  as a function of $\theta_1,\theta_2$, at the expense of continuity of $f$.

This is of little use.